# Xposed framework greyed out. Should I be concerned?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, xposed-framework

Xposed framework (ver 85) on my device Moto X Play has options greyed out as shown - only *soft reboot* and *reboot* are not greyed out

[image]

This happened over last three days when I was trying out some modules , so can't pinpoint which caused it

1. Xposed framework and modules are working fine
2. Restoring Framework from earlier TiBu backup which didn't have this problem did not help - it remains greyed out
3. Clearing cache and data of installer also didn't help

I've come across cases on Internet where this is associated with framework not working properly or wrong framework installed, which clearly isn't the case here ( it was installed many months ago )

So my question is, **should I be concerned about it ?**

My feeling is that it's not causing any problems (Point 1) , so it's pointless going through uninstalling and installing it. But just to be sure, wanted a second opinion on this, maybe with reasons why this happened

Comment: Does the Installer have root permissions?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman: checked. Yes, it has

Comment: I've no answer this time, as I'm using Nougat. What I can say, is that I once stumbled on the same behavior.

Comment: Could you share (| link to) your Xposed Installer APK?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman: I think it was downloaded using PC , which isn't accessible now, do not sure of the link. If it helps, it says Ver 85 as in screenshot and in about it says *3.0 alpha 4*

Comment: I don't recall from where I downloaded it but [here](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=xposed+installer+3.0+alpha4&oq=xposed+installer+3.0+a&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3.25824j0j4&client=ms-android-motorola&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) are possible sources @DeathMaskSalesman

Comment: I also had v3.0 alpha 4 release downloaded from rovo89's official thread and so as the framework. This greyed out issue persisted but it did not affect anything in my Android 6.0.1. I now use v3.1.1 (unofficial; material design) installer.

Comment: @Firelord :  Thanks, I got company :).  It just happened a few days ago, before that it was fine, that set me wondering

Answer (score 1):

I used Xposed some time ago and as far I can remember those buttons are grayed out because on marshmallow (possibly lollipop) you must flash framework files via .zip file. Maybe I'm wrong and forgot something. 
Are you sure it happened recently, that it wasn't there all the time?
However I don't think you should be concerned because Xposed and it's modules work fine (right?).
It says "Xposed framework 85 is active"

Comment: Thanks. Very sure it happened recently. As I said, it may not make a difference but thought somebody may know the reason

Answer (score 0):

When Xposed Installer (`de.robv.android.xposed.installer`) can't connect to its server, the install buttons will grey out. Check your internet connection.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. My internet is working fine. I have no firewalls to filter either. Besides, after seeing your answer, was able to update one of the modules using the installer

Comment: @beeshyams Remember a [SF] can also be the cause. I should emphasize **your connection to the Xposed server**.

Comment: Possible but if that was the case , would I be able to update a module ? Not sure if modules are located elsewhere .

Comment: @beeshyams Modules are in `repo.xposed.info`, which does not seem to be the place where flashable zips lies.

Comment: That's a possibility. Thanks. It's been happening for two days now, so will wait and watch if it resolves over time, when the server fault is fixed. Do you happen to know the domain to check out?

Comment: @iBug By the way, flashable zips are located at [dl-xda.xposed.info](http://dl-xda.xposed.info/framework/).

Comment: @beeshyams Try pinging `70.34.227.107`.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman: since I don't have access to my computer, used [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ua.com.streamsoft.pingtools) to ping and it passed. No problems. Thanks for providing domain